# Silverstripe if else loop

Tags: if-statement, silverstripe

```
<div class="related">
<% if $RelatedOne.Title != null %>

<a href="$Link" class="play">
    <div class="clip" style="background-image:url('$RelatedOne.VideoImage.CroppedImage(215,120).URL')">
        <img src="$RelatedOne.VideoImage.CroppedImage(215,120).URL" alt="$RelatedOne.Title">
    </div>
    <span class="overlay">
        <span class="title vertical-align">$RelatedOne.Title</span>
        <span class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
    </span>
</a>


<% else %>
    <% include RelatedVideos %>
<% end_if %>
```

When the title is there the if condition is working properly but for others the else section is not working.Could anyone please point out my mistake.

Comment: i doubt you can check against null in the template. Isn't Title just a varchar? Have you tried  `<% if $RelatedOne.Title %>` ? This would check for "not an empty string".

Comment: I removed the not null condition it's working now.Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @wmk, can you please add your comment as an answer? I think a few people might find this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I> doubt you can explicitly check against `null` in the template. But isn't `$Title` just a Varchar? So it won't be `null`, just empty...

Have you tried this:

```
<% if $RelatedOne.Title %>
```

This would check for "not an empty string".